# ADB equivalent for iOS device with windows PC

Tags: python, ios, go, debugging, adb

I was looking some instrument like Android ADB in order to debug iOS devices. I've found iOS instrument, a tool of the XCode that is able to debug app on mobile iOS devices.

Any idea or comment is greatly appreciated by me.

I would like to know if it's possible execute a touch on the iOS device, such as input events like "tap", "swipe", "drag", "flick", save image screen in similar manner of ABD shell for android devices.

I am using OS win10pro, and iOS 15.1.

Comment: We have two close votes here. Please explain the reason or provide suggestion for OP to improve the question. To me, this post is looking for iOS app testability techniques and will benefit the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open source tool set "libimobiledevice" which also exists for [Windows](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net/releases).

This set of tools include e.g. `ideviceinstaller` for transmitting and installing IPA files on an connected iPhone, `idevice_id` for getting the connected iPhone UUIDs, `idevicescreenshot` and many more tools.

In addition you need the "Apple Mobile Device Services" installed and running. THis service is included in the Apple's iTunes for Windows. You don't need install complete iTunes, if you don't want to. You can just extract the iTunes Windows installer to get the Installer for Apple Mobile services.

Real shell access is only possible for jailbroken iOS devices. Usually in the process of jailbreaking you have an option to install ssh daemon which you can access via USB (use iproxy for set-up port forwarding of port 22 to the iPhone).